# Get only one image of ng-repeat for a background image

Tags: javascript, angularjs, indexing, angularjs-ng-repeat

Trying to just grab one image from an ng-repeat to use as a background image for a div. Have this so far:

```
<div ng-repeat="photo in inventory.photos">
<div class="details-image" style="background-image: url({{photo}})">
            </div>
</div>
```

Which of course is showing all the photos. How would I grab just the first image of that group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="photo in inventory.photos">
    <div class="details-image" style="background-image: url({{inventory.photos[0]}})">
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope you are not looping through the photos just for the purspose of getting the first one. If you are, then you wouldn't even need the ng-repeat.

```
<div>
    <div class="details-image" style="background-image: url({{inventory.photos[0]}})">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: :) I was but your second sample was what I needed. Still unbinding my mind from jQuery so the fact that I can get what I need by simply doing call the index of the object in the array is still blowing my mind.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the `$first`, `$middle`, or `$last`.
For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="photo in inventory.photos">
<div class="details-image" style="background-image: url({{inventory.photos[$first]}})">
            </div>
</div>
```

Link [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). Check out how the `$first`, `$middle`, or `$last` and `$index` work

Comment: This is the answer I was about to give. You probably have you reasons for still using ng-repeat. You could also use an ng-if to see if $index === 0 to toggle the entire div.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ng-repeat, just select first

```
    <div class="details-image" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url('+ inventory.photos[0]+')'">
    </div>
```